# calling an identity async method from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have added a bunch of properties to the standard identity user (main properties of interest here are ImageData and ImageMimeType). Now I need to display the user's picture in my view. My ImageController has the following method:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FileContentResult> GetImageByUser(string id)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    return File(user.ImageData, user.ImageMimeType);
}
```

In my view, I just need to display the returned file as follows:

```
<img id="ContestantPicture" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="50" scr="@Url.Action("GetImageByUser", "Image", new { id = Model.UserParticipation.UserId })" />
```

Needless to say the image does not display on the view. I am not too familiar with Tasks in C# so am not quite sure how to fix this.

Comment: shouldn't be attribute "src" instead of "scr" ?

Comment: That was embarrassing. Great catch. Thank you @Nps